# How to random generate fully saturated colors only?

Tags: .net, graphics, bitmap

I normally use the following code to generate random colors:

```
Random rand = new Random();

Color random = Color.FromArgb((int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), 
                              (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255), 
                              (int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255));
```

But most of them look like a variation of gray. How can I restrict the output to only fully saturated colors?

Thanks.

Comment: The expression `(int)(rand.NextDouble() * 255)` will never generate the value `255`. `NextDouble` generates a number such that 0 <= x < 1.0. If you want to generate values from 0 to 255, inclusive, you need to change your number to 256. But then, why not just use `rand.Next(256)` and be done with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Theory**

Full Saturation (as used by HSL and similar colour schemes) in effect means that you have one RGB value at full, one at 0 and one at any other value.

The reason for this is that the saturation is based on the difference between the highest and lowest colour components and is highest when they are at the extremes. The actual definitions are more complicated (and involve the luminance) but it is sufficient to say that a component of 0 and another of 1 will give max saturation.

**Algorithm 1**

This leads to a relatively simple way of doing it.

1. Generate a random number between 0 and 1.
2. Assign this number randomly to one fo the R, G and B elements.
3. Randomly assign zero to one of the remaining elements.
4. set the final element to 1.

This will give you a maximum saturation colour relatively simply.

For implementation it is probably easiest to generate a random number 1 to 6 for the 6 possible choices of which component you assign the 0, 1 and random element to and then use a switch of some kind.

This is the easiest algorithm but not necessarily the easiest implementation due to the choices/branching.

**Algorithm 2**

Second method as suggested by Jim Mischel based on a similar theory but just implemented a bit differently.

1. Generate random values for each of the R, G and B components
2. Find the max component.
3. Find the min component.
4. Set max component to 1.
5. Set min component to 0.

This has the same effect of setting one value to 1, one to 0 and one to a random value. It has the advantage that it doesn't require you to use the messy switch statement but you might end up with some messy loops instead. Also depending on the precision of your components (eg if you go straight in with bytes) then if your mid value is actually equal to your top or bottom (or all three are the same) then this might get reset too depending on how you code your algorithm. This will mainly have the effect of skewing the randomness but this is not likely to be significantly noticeable.

Code implementation for method two also courtesy of Jim

```
    int[] rgb = new int[3];
    rgb[0] = rnd.Next(256);  // red
    rgb[1] = rnd.Next(256);  // green
    rgb[2] = rnd.Next(256);  // blue

    // Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

    // find max and min indexes.
    int max, min;

    if (rgb[0] > rgb[1])
    {
        max = (rgb[0] > rgb[2]) ? 0 : 2
        min = (rgb[1] < rgb[2]) ? 1 : 2;
    }
    else
    {
        max = (rgb[1] > rgb[2]) ? 1 : 2;
        int notmax = 1 + max % 2;
        min = (rgb[0] < rgb[notmax]) ? 0 : notmax;
    }
    rgb[max] = 255;
    rgb[min] = 0;

    // Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

Comment: Interesting. Another way to do it would be to generate three random numbers (for R, G, and B). Then, push the highest to 1 and the lowest to 0.

Comment: Yup. That'd work too. Will almost certainly be neater code too without the messy switch.

Comment: @JimMischel: I've added in your suggestion to my answer. I assume you don't mind...

Comment: The idea was yours. I just suggested a different implementation. I illustrated with an example in an answer of my own. Truthfully, I'd rather you incorporated that in your answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Done. I neatened up the max/min calcs in the first if. You had a bit of redundancy in there (I think) that I got rid of. Do shout (or just edit) if I got confused. :)

Comment: Good catch on the redundancy.

Comment: "This has the same effect of setting [...] one to a random value": this is wrong, since you pickup the min and max random values, the remaining one _do not have a flat random distribution between 0 and 1_. A simpler and correct way: set rgb[0] = 0, rgb[1] = 255 and rgb[2] = random(256), then shuffle randomly the array.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to generate your colors in HSL values setting the saturation fixed to it's max value and only randomize the hue and lightness. You can find a class for a HSL color [here](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/hslcolor-class/).

Comment: It may be that you want to fix Luminance at 0.5 (ie the midpoint) since above that it tends to white and below that to black so you may end up with the same colour bunching problem you had before (ie the nearer to 0 and 1 the luminance the less difference you are going to see for different H even with max saturation.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is a small adaptation to *Jim Mischel* suggestion (below is Java code, adaptation to .net is trivial):

```
private static Random r = new Random();

public static final String randomColor() {
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 0x80;
    arr[1] = 0xFF;
    arr[2] = r.nextInt(0x10) * 8 + 0x80;
    // Fisher–Yates shuffle
    for (int i1 = arr.length - 1; i1 >= 0; i1--) {
        int i2 = r.nextInt(i1 + 1);
        int tmp = arr[i2];
        arr[i2] = arr[i1];
        arr[i1] = tmp;
    }
    return String.format("%02x%02x%02x", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
}
```

We set 3 values randomly:

- one to 0x80
- another to 0xFF
- the remaining one to a random value between 0X80 and 0xFF.

The random value is generated with steps of 0x10 to get a reduced set of different colors (namely 6 x 8 = 48), you can write `arr[2] = r.nextInt(0x80) + 0x80;` for more choices.

I also set the minimum value to 0x80 to get less saturated color which are in my sense a bit more better looking (it's a matter of bad taste...). You can reduce this minimum to increase saturation.